# How do I solve and plot a system of ODEs with R?

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations, desolve

I have a system of odes,

[image: equations]

I want to plot V1 and V2 against time t. My code for that is

```
library("deSolve")
library("reshape")
library("tidyverse")

parameters <- c(tau = 0.005, tau_r = 0.0025, mui=0, Ve=0.06, Vi=-0.01, s=0.015, mue=10000)

state <- c(X = 0.015, Y = 0)

Odesolver <-function(t, state, parameters) {
 with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
 # rate of change
 dX <- -(1/tau + mue - mui)*X + (Y-X)/tau_r + mue*Ve - mui*Vi
 dY <- -Y/tau + (X-Y)/tau_r

 # return the rate of change
 list(c(dX, dY))
 }) # end with(as.list ...
 }

times <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.01)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = Odesolver, parms = parameters)
out.df = as.data.frame(out)
out.m = melt(out.df, id.vars='time')

p <- ggplot(out.m, aes(time, value, color = variable)) + geom_point() +theme_classic()
print(p)
```

Am I doing it right? Also is there a way for me to plot `1/t` for changing values of `mue`? Both of these are related through the first ode.

Comment: What do you mean with `1/t`for changing values of `mue`? Do you mean different simulations with different `mue` or some internal variable in dependence of `t`or `1/t`?

Answer (score 0):

The translation of the ode system looks plausible, but the parameter values produced a somewhat extreme behaviour. I don't know what the model is about, so I changed some of the parameters arbitrarily to get a more plausible output. I also changed `X` and `Y` to `V1` and `V2` according to the system of equations. What I don't understand is what you mean with your question. Do you want to compare simulations with different values of `mue`? And, what is `t`?

Here a slightly modified version of the model with alternative suggestions how to plot the output:

```r
library("deSolve")
library("reshape")
library("tidyverse")

## parameters of the original poster show extreme behaviour
# parameters <- c(tau = 0.005, tau_r = 0.0025, mui=0, Ve=0.06, Vi=-0.01, s=0.015, mue=10000)

## parameter values arbitrarily changed, 
## so that the output looks somewhat more plausible. 

parameters <- c(tau = 5, tau_r = 50, mui=0, Ve=0.06, Vi=-0.01, s=0.015, mue=0.001)

state <- c(V1 = 0.015, V2 = 0)

## rename to derivative as these are the equations and not the solver 
derivative <-function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    # rate of change
    dV1 <- -(1/tau + mue - mui)*V1 + (V2-V1)/tau_r + mue*Ve - mui*Vi
    dV2 <- -V2/tau + (V1-V2)/tau_r
    
    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dV1, dV2))
  }) # end with(as.list ...
}

times <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.01)

## ode is the ode solver
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = derivative, parms = parameters)

## this is deSolve's built-in plot method
plot(out) 

## version of the original poster
out.df   <- as.data.frame(out)
out.m <- melt(out.df, id.vars='time')

p <- ggplot(out.m, aes(time, value, color = variable)) + geom_point() + theme_classic()
print(p)

## alternative with dplyr and tidyr
out %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, color = name)) + geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, thank you for your comments, they are helpful :) and I think my last question is perhaps a bit misguided. The parameter values are alright, I just needed to have a bigger mu value (100 or above). I basically need to see when V2 crosses the S=0.015 threshold for different mu values, to get an idea of how the input mu drives the behavior of V2.